Is there a way to numerically determine the expectation E[f(Z)] where Z is Poisson Random Variable with parameter lambda?
As $E[f(Z)]=\Sigma_{z=0}^{\infty} f(z)Pr(Z=z) $ and $Z \sim Poiss(\lambda)$. The question I want to specifically ask is that if there is a standard way to truncate this summation when I am determining the expectation numerically.

Of course there's no standard way,  because $f$ could be anything.  Could you tell us more about the $f$ in which you are interested?

It might interest you to know that the expectation of interest to you is the Poisson generating function of the function $f$, which is also closely related to the exponential generating function of $f$.  This is given by:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(f(Z))
&= \sum_{z=0}^\infty f(z) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{z=0}^\infty f(z) \cdot \frac{\lambda^z}{z!} \cdot \exp(-\lambda) 
= \text{PG}(f|\lambda) \\[6pt]
&= \exp(-\lambda) \sum_{z=0}^\infty f(z) \cdot \frac{\lambda^z}{z!} 
= \text{EG}(f|\lambda) \cdot \exp(-\lambda). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Naturally, the particular form of the generating function depends on the function $f$.  In some cases it has a closed form that allows exact computation.  In other cases, it may be possible to compute with arbitrary precision using truncation so long as the function $f$ does not increase too quickly as its argument goes to infinity.  As an example, consider bounding the function using the MGF of the Poisson distribution by supposing that there is some $N$ and $t$ such that:
$$f(z) \leqslant \exp(tz)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } z \geqslant N.$$
If this bound on $f$ holds then we can choose any value $n \geqslant N$ and we have the upper bound:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(f(Z))
&= \sum_{z=0}^\infty f(z) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{z=0}^{n-1} f(z) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) + \sum_{z=n}^\infty f(z) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) \\[6pt]
&\leqslant \sum_{z=0}^{n-1} f(z) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) + \sum_{z=n}^\infty \exp(tz) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{z=0}^{n-1} [f(z) - \exp(tz)] \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) + \sum_{z=0}^\infty \exp(tz) \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{z=0}^{n-1} [f(z) - \exp(tz)] \cdot \text{Pois}(z|\lambda) + \exp(\lambda(e^t-1)). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
This upper bound is in closed form and can be computed in a finite number of operations.  By taking a sufficiently large value of $n$ we can bound the expectation of interest with arbitrary precision.
